# How to disable 'devTools' in Capacitor + Electron app

Tags: electron, devtools, capacitor

To disable devTools we need to access webPreferences through BrowserWindow, However BrowserWindow is not available directly from the Electron app. So how do we access webPreferences to diable the devTools?

Without Capcitor Below code snippet works perfectly fine

```
const browserWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  .....
webPreferences: { devTools: false}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let config: CapacitorElectronConfig = {
    mainWindow: { 
    windowOptions: { 
    webPreferences: {
     devTools: false
     }
    }
  }
 }
```

While creating Capacitor Electron app, we just need to pass on the configuration.

```
const myCapacitorApp = createCapacitorElectronApp(config);
```